# R: find and count all differences by position (of one element added, subtracted or substituted) between character vectors nested in a list

Tags: r, performance, position, set-difference

I have a list of character vectors representing words split in phonemes:

```
> head(words)
[[1]]
[1] "UU"

[[2]]
[1] "EY" "Z" 

[[3]]
[1] "T"  "R"  "IH" "P"  "UU" "L"  "EY"

[[4]]
[1] "AA" "B"  "ER" "G" 

[[5]]
[1] "AA" "K"  "UU" "N" 

[[6]]
[1] "AA" "K"  "ER"
```

For each word in the list, I would like to find the number of words that differ from the considered word by one phoneme (one phoneme added, subtracted or substituted) and have the same number of
phonemes in the same positions. 
In this sense, for the word `"EY" "Z"` acceptable cases would be:

```
[1] "M"  "EY" "Z" 

[1] "AY" "Z"

[1] "EY" "D" 

[1] "EY" "Z" "AH"
```

But the following cases should be rejected:

```
[1] "EY" "D"  "Z"

[1] "Z" "EY" "D"

[1] "HH" "EY"
```

Basically, I would like to find differences of one element respecting the  positions of the phonemes in the vectors. 
At the moment, the best solution I have found is:

```
diffs <- c()
for (i in seq_along(words)) {
  diffs <- c(diffs, sum(sapply(words, function(y) {
    count <- 0
    elements <- list(words[[i]], y)
    len <- c(length(words[[i]]), length(y))
    if (identical(elements[which(len==max(len))][[1]][-1], elements[which(len==min(len))][[1]]) == 1) {
      count + identical(elements[which(len==max(len))][[1]][-1], elements[which(len==min(len))][[1]])
    } else {
      length(elements[which(len==min(len))][[1]]) <- length(elements[which(len==max(len))][[1]])
      elements <- rapply(elements, f=function(x) ifelse(is.na(x),"$$",x), how="replace" )
      count + sum(elements[[1]] != elements[[2]])
    }
  })== 1))
}
```

However, this solution is taking ages because my list `words` has 120.000 elements (words/vectors), so I would like to ask if you know other solutions to speed up the process.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers

Comment: How many phonemes exist?

Comment: Hi, this are all possible phonemes (forty):
"UU" "EY" "Z"  "T"  "R"  "IH" "P"  "L"  "AA" "B"  "ER" "G"  "K"  "N"  "S"  "EH" "TH" "M"  "AO" "D"  "V"  "IY" "AE" "OW" "NG" "SH" "HH" "AW" "UW" "AH" "F"  "AY" "JH" "Y"  "CH" "W"  "ZH" "UH" "DH" "OY"

Comment: And in the case of complete equality, you count this as 0 (not a 1)?

Comment: Why `[1] "EY" "D"  "Z"` is not an acceptable case? Does it means that you can add just at the beginning or the end? Is this the same for removing?

Comment: Hi F.! Thank you very much for your help. The equality would counted as 0. 
For what concerns the case [1] "EY" "D" "Z", Christoph noticed that my script is considering the add or remove cases only at the beginning and at the end of a string. 
For the work I'm doing I am not completely sure at the moment which rule I'm supposed to use, so I kindly ask you if you could suggest me both solutions, one similar to mine, and the other considering adding and removing in any possible position of a string as Christoph's script does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And a different answer, using regular Levenshtein distance (i.e. allowing insertions at any point), but this time FAST - 1000 words in 15 seconds fast.

The trick is using one of the fast Levenshtein implementations available in R packages; in this case I'm using `stringdist` but any should work. The issue is that they operate on strings and characters, not multi-character phoneme representations. But there's a trivial solution for that: as there are more characters than phonemes, we can just translate the phonemes into single characters. The resulting strings are unreadable as phonemic transcriptions, but work perfectly fine as input to the neighborhood density algorithm.

```
library(stringdist)

phonemes <- unique(unlist(words))

# add a few buffer characters
targets <- c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9, "!", "§", "%", "&", "/", "=", 
             "#")[1:length(phonemes)]

ptmap <- targets
names(ptmap) <- phonemes

wordsT <- sapply(words, function(i) paste0(ptmap[i], collapse=""))

wordlengths <- nchar(wordsT)

onediffs.M <- function(x) {
  lengthdiff <-  abs(wordlengths - nchar(x))
  sum(stringdist(x, wordsT[lengthdiff == 0], method="hamming") == 1) +
    sum(stringdist(x, wordsT[lengthdiff == 1], method="lv") == 1)
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks very much. After reading your first answer, I also thought to convert the phonemes in unique characters to use adist() then. 
At the end I was trying with this solution: 
`neigh_lev <- unlist(lapply(words_converted, function(y) {
  sum(unlist(lapply(words_converted, function(x) {
    adist(y, x)[1,1]
  }) == 1))
}))`
But it was not so fast because I didn't think to discount the cases where the absolute difference in length between words is more than 1.

Comment: Good thinking. But subselecting by length is only half the story. The other issue is that you call `adist` with a single pair of words; this means that R has to keep jumping between the relatively slow R code and the fast native code. Both `adist` and stringdist are vectorized, so they can handle vectors as input. This is much simpler code, and about ten times faster than your version: `unlist(lapply(wordsT[1:10], function(y) { sum(adist(y, wordsT) == 1)}))`. The version in the answer could probably still be made about twice as fast by not calculating everything twice.

Comment: These are valuable explanations for me. Thank you again Christoph

Answer (score 1):

So, the key here is to separate words with respect to their lengths so that we can test each asumption (substitution/addition/deletion) only on a subset of interest.

```
get_one_diff <- function(words) {

  K <- max(le <- lengths(words))
  i_chr <- as.character(seq_len(K))
  words.spl <- split(words, le)

  test_substitution <- function(i) {
    word1 <- words[[i]]
    do.call(sum, lapply(words.spl[[i_chr[le[i]]]], function(word2) {
      sum(word1 != word2) == 1
    }))
  }

  test_addition <- function(i) {
    if ((le <- le[i]) == K) return(0)
    word1 <- words[[i]]
    do.call(sum, lapply(words.spl[[i_chr[le + 1]]], function(word2) {
      isOneDiff(word1, word2)
    }))
  }

  test_deletion <- function(i) {
    if ((le <- le[i]) == 1) return(0)
    word1 <- words[[i]]
    do.call(sum, lapply(words.spl[[i_chr[le - 1]]], function(word2) {
      isOneDiff(word2, word1)
    }))
  }

  sapply(seq_along(words), function(i) {
    test_substitution(i) + test_addition(i) + test_deletion(i)
  })
}
```

where `isOneDiff` is an Rcpp function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool isOneDiff(const StringVector& w1,
               const StringVector& w2) {

  int i, n = w1.size();

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) if (w1[i] != w2[i]) break;
  for (     ; i < n; i++) if (w1[i] != w2[i+1]) return false;

  return true;
}
```

This is 20 times as fast as your version and as it is merely an `sapply`, it could be easily parallelized.

Comment: Hi F.! Thank you so much. The performance of your solution would help me a lot! However, when I try to run it an error occurs: "Error in words.spl[[i_chr[le - 1]]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index". Would you mind giving me an extra help suggesting how to fix the problem?

Comment: Also, as I ask you above,  Christoph noticed that my script is considering the add or remove cases only at the beginning and at the end of a string. For the work I'm doing I am not completely sure at the moment which rule I'm supposed to use, so I kindly ask you if you could suggest me both solutions, one similar to mine, and the other considering adding and removing in any possible position of a string as Christoph's script does

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using Levenshtein Distance with the Wagner-Fischer algorithm.

```
vecLeven <- function(s, t) {
  d <- matrix(0, nrow = length(s) + 1, ncol=length(t) + 1)
  d[, 1] <- (1:nrow(d)) - 1
  d[1,] <- (1:ncol(d))-1
  for (i in 1:length(s))  {
    for (j in 1:length(t)) {
      d[i+1, j+1] <- min(
        d[i, j+1] + 1, # deletion
        d[i+1, j] + 1, # insertion
        d[i, j] + if (s[i] == t[j]) 0 else 1 # substitution
      )
    }
  }

  d[nrow(d), ncol(d)]
}


onediff <- sapply(words[1:10], function(x) {
  lengthdiff <- sapply(words, function(word) abs(length(word) - length(x)))
  sum(sapply(words[lengthdiff == 0], function(word) sum(word != x) == 1)) +
        sum(mapply(vecLeven, list(x), words[lengthdiff == 1]) == 1)
})
```

I tested both versions on the CMU dictionary, which has a similar size. It's a bit faster than your version (about 30 seconds instead of 50 for 10 words), and should parallelize well. Still, running it on the complete data set would take several days.

One large performance factor is that all pairs are computed twice, once for th first word and once for the second; doing a lookup instead would halve that. However, there are more than 7 billion pairs, so you would need a database to store them.

Comment: Hi Christoph! Thank you very much for your answer. This algorithm is very interesting. Actually I'm doing this calculation using the CMU dictionary. I would like to have a value of neighborhood density (the calculation I explained above) for each word in the dictionary. 
Unfortunately I have noticed that your script is giving me different values. Do you think there's a way to know which are the words that for your script is evaluating as neighbours for example for the first word? Just to have a way to compare what the two functions are doing.

Comment: Hi Francesco, yes there is, just get get both algorithms to output all neighbors for one word and compare them. For "'course", your algorithm e.g. does not find "courts. I think the detection of cases with unequal lengths is wrong, and you only consider removing the first phoneme of the longest word instead of all of them and taking the shorter one. But I might misunderstand the algorithm.

Comment: Ah, you exclude cases where insertions are in the middle in your example. That makes it a much easier task. It's not the standard definition of neighborhood density though, it it?

Comment: Hi Christoph! thank you. I have just started working with phonological neighbourhood so probably I have not well understood the definition as you said. I know that this place is only for programming topics, but could you please provide me a link where I can read a clear definition of neighbourhood density so that I can be sure that it's necessary to include also the insertions in the middle of a word and edit my original question here? 
And also, do you know if the neighbouhood density of each word of the CMU already exist somewhere on the internet? 
Anyway thank you very much for your help

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if a public list of CMUdict neighborhood distance exists. I also don't have a canonical reference on hand, Baayen occasionally uses it in his textbook (2009, Analyzing Linguistic Data, CUP), so you can probably look up the original articles and see his definition. Also see here: http://corpustools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/neighborhood_density.html But the one i remember reading is essentially just "Words that differ in one phoneme/grapheme etc.",  so I don't see a clear reason to leave them out.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help Christoph, I have looked into it and I'm definitely going to use the Levenshtein Edit Distance, which seems the best common way to calculate neighbourhood density. And looking at different papers and reading the definition there is no reason to exclude those cases  as you noted.